# Python package : data files of a subpackage

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following structure for a package :

```
├───Docs
│   ├───Dir
│   └───Output
└───MyPackage
    ├───__init__.py
    ├───test
    ├───MySubPackage1
    │   ├───__init__.py
    │   ├───...
    │   └───data
    │         └─── data.pth
    └───MySubPackage2
        └───__init__.py
```

I need to include the `data.pth` file so I tried as advise [there](https://ep2015.europython.eu/media/conference/slides/less-known-packaging-features-and-tricks.pdf) to use a `MANIFEST.IN` like this :

```
MANIFEST.IN

graft data
```

```
setup.py

setup(name='MyPackage',
      version='1.0',
      package_dir={"MyPackage": "MyPackage"},
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True)
```

but when installing :

```
python setup.py install
```

I see the following warning:

```
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no directories found matching 'data'
```

what is the correct way to handle this data that sits within a subpackage with a `MANIFEST.IN` ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `package_data` argument to `setup()` to explicitly note data files that must be included in your packages or sub-packages.  This is how I usually go about it, and such files don't need to be included explicitly in MANIFEST.in:

```py
setup(
    ...
    package_data={'MyPackage.MySubPackage': ['data.pth']}
)
```

for example.  See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

I think you might have another minor oops in your `setup()` which is `package_dir={"MyPackage": "MyPackage"}`.

`package_dir` is used to specify the top-level directory within your source tree in which a Python packages to be installed is found.  By default it is `''` (indicating the top-level of the source).

From the source tree you posted, it looks like `MyPackage` is already at the top-level of the source so you don't need this option at all; it's redundant.  I believe that the way you've written it *does* work.  But `package_dir` is more often used in cases where you have alternate source hierarchies.  The most common is having a `src/` directory your Python packages are found in, in which case you specify `package_dir={'': 'src/'}` which means all Python packages are found under `src/`.  In your case I don't think you need this.

Comment: Yes but it is discouraged here : https://ep2015.europython.eu/media/conference/slides/less-known-packaging-features-and-tricks.pdf. I completely agree with you with the use of  `package_dir`. It's indeed more useful when having e.g. `src/mypackage`. But it works :)

Comment: I don't agree with that, and it appears unjustified, though I have some vague memory about arguing with Ionel about exact that a long time ago.  This is what the option is there for.  Some of this comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I thought `setuptools` was able to understand package and subpackages structure when reading the `MANIFEST.in` but this is apparently not the case.

Doing this :

```
MANIFEST.IN

graft MyPackage/MySubPackage1/data
```

solves the issue